# what conclusion can i get from this experinment?

Tags: opencl

I get the execution time of vector adder with different size of groupsize and I only use one group in this experiment.

```
groupsize --------execution time
1 ----------------3.6
50 ---------------4.22
100 --------------4.3
200 --------------4.28
300 --------------4.3
400 --------------4.31
500 --------------4.38
600 --------------4.38
700 --------------4.78
800 --------------5.18
900 --------------5.78
1000 -------------6.4
```

Can I get the conclusion one sm can work about 600 workitems together?
and I have some questions, could anybody can help me?

Why does the execution time increase sharply when groupsize increases from 1 to 50 and from 600 to 1000?

thank you very much

Comment: Is the execution time you provided second or millisecond? Can you also provide the code? The thing is, If in every experiment, you have 1 group and the groupsize changes, are you getting the right results? Because, that looks like in the first one, you are only running one thread and that's it. The table does not make any sense without any further information provided.

Comment: if its microseconds, it could be launch overhead too.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see some code, both of the kernel and the host enqueueing parameters. The conclusions also depend on what sort of hardware you're running this on - GPU, CPU, accelerator, FPGA, …?

A few ideas:

- GPUs typically can run power-of-2 number of threads in parallel in an execution unit. You will likely get better results if you try e.g. 16, 32, 64, 128, etc. CPUs and other accelerators typically have SIMD-widths which are powers of 2 too, for example x86-64 SSE registers can hold 4 floats, AVX 8, AVX512 16, etc. so it most likely will help there, too.
- As you can vary group size so freely, I'm going to assume your work-items don't need to coordinate among each other via `local` memory or barriers. (The problem is [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel).) A group size of 1 in theory allows your compiler, driver, and hardware maximum flexibility for distributing work-items to threads and parallel execution units optimally. So it should not be a surprise that this is the fastest. (Depending on register pressure and memory access patterns it can still sometimes be helpful to manually increase group size for specific types of hardware in the embarrassingly parallel case.)
- On GPUs, all items in a work group must run on the same execution unit, in order to be able to coordinate and share local memory. So by increasing the group size, you're limiting the number of execution units the workload can be spread across, and the execution units need to run your work-items serially - you're reducing parallelism. Above 600 you're probably submitting fewer workgroups than your hardware has execution units.